# How to get two working project under one repository?

Tags: git, github, repo

I have two git repositories one is a **(react-guide)** and the other one is **(web-HTTP-Ajax)**. So I want to put that  (web-HTTP-Ajax) repo under (react-guide) repository creating a new branch *ex. section-9* in **(react-guide)** repository. It can possible? How can I do it?

Comment: simplest way I would do it is just make a branch in react-guide and copy all the files to it then push it. Result would be one repo that has a section-9 branch that has your repo files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches are for isolating a development effort of *one* code base, not to create folders.

A possible solution would be to add your Web-HTTP-Ajax repository under react-guide, as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), using [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt):

```
cd react-guide
git submodule add /url/of/Web-HTTP-Ajax
```